# Update version in appengine-web.xml by current svn revision number

Tags: xml, svn, google-app-engine, command-line-interface, revision

We are trying to update appengine version number automatically based on svn revision number.

This is the appengine-web.xml file:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>XYZ</application>
    <version>5646</version>
        ....
```

How do we replace 5646 with the current svn revision number automatically in a daily basis?

Ideally, it is a command line and has something to do with 'svnversion' (which output looks like 10358:10359 ).

Answer (score 1):

I had to write again and again:

If you can use Windows CLI-programs, youhave to use [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) from TortoiseSVN:

- Write and add to repo template-file for appengine-web.xml, there version string replaced by [SubWCRev-keyword](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html) ($WCREV$ in your case)
- When you want to have real data in xml-file, run SubWCRev in your Working Copy, get final file. Useit

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might seem like an annoyance, but it is easiest if you convert your project to a Maven Project. Then, you can use plugins like the [maven-buildNumber-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) to dynamically replace any values you want (using the stardard [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/)) in any of your build files.

The caveat is that you must use the [maven-gae-plugin](http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/) to compile and deploy your applications. I use Eclipse and it just means that rather than using the Google App Engine buttons in the UI, you just make a build configuration (i.e. *gae:deploy*), and then just click the build button in the future.

The upside is that now you can do near any number of complex build step modifications to your project, and via the magic of Maven, you don't need to download any extra plugins or jars beyond Maven itself, since it will just fetch and install them for you. This makes it easier for other people to check your GAE app out of a sparse SVN and build it any time.

Comment: I totally agree. It would be nice if you can put a sample code here, cause we don't know how to change appengine-web.xml from maven.